# Flutter - AutoRouter pass arguments

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-routes

I am trying to pass argument value while navigating using `auto_router` package.
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

page1.dart

```
class Page1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const Page1({Key? key, required this.text}) : super(key: key);
  final String text;
  @override
  _Page1State createState() => _Page1State();
}

class _Page1State extends State<Page1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.text);
  }
}
```

mainpage.dart

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:test/Page1.dart';
import 'routes/router.gr.dart';

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainPageState createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  String data = 'Pass this value';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: (){
          context.router.push(Page1(text: data));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

router.dart

```
import 'package:auto_route/auto_route.dart';
import 'package:test/Page1.dart';
import 'package:test/main_page.dart';
    @MaterialAutoRouter(
      replaceInRouteName: 'Page,Route',
      routes: <AutoRoute>[
        CustomRoute(
          page: MainPage,
          initial: true,
        ),
        CustomRoute(
          page: Page1,
        ),
      ],
    )
    class $AppRouter {}
```

I am trying to navigate to `page1` from `main_page.dart` using `named route` with passing argument of data.

I am getting this error:

```
error: The argument type 'Page1' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PageRouteInfo<dynamic>'. (argument_type_not_assignable at [test] lib\main_page.dart:20)
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use instance of `PageRouteInfo` class instead of widget instance itself as parameter for `push` method, i.e. use this code:

```
context.router.push(Page1Route(text: data));
```

instead of this:

```
context.router.push(Page1(text: data));
```

As documentation [says](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#generated-routes):

> A PageRouteInfo object will be generated for every declared AutoRoute,
> These objects hold path information plus strongly-typed page arguments
> which are extracted from the page's default constructor. Think of them
> as string path segments on steroid.

Take a closer look on [example calls](https://pub.dev/packages/auto_route#navigating-between-screens).